# Detect touch move over separate elements to detect and change elements color

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I have a series of elements, I want the user to touch the first element, then drag their finger across a number of subsequent elements. I can detect the initial touch with the (touchstart) event, I can detect movement with the (touchmove) event, however that event only triggers on the initial element, even if the touch area has moved away from the element. touchstart/touchmove isn’t triggered on any subsequent element during the action. How can I detect when they are moving over subsequent elements?

can anyone help me with this?

[screen of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ3P2.png)

Comment: Ask your question by providing the cord which you are using.

Comment: cord? i didn't get you. screenshot is attached with it.